# Wifi card not detected meditatek mt7921e on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, wireless, mediatek

I'm dual booting Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11. My wifi card is Mediatek mt7921e. Laptop model: Asus TUF Gaming f15.

Ubuntu sometimes can't detect my wifi interface. This happens totally randomly. When that happens, the output of `sudo lshw -C network` and `sudo lspci` doesn't show any output for my wifi card. Plus from the settings also the `PCI Wifi` option completely disappears. I have done several reinstalls of ubuntu but the problem persists. The problem also persists when I boot into Windows where it says:
`Currently this hardware device is not connected to the computer. (Code 45)`

Also, in the times when wifi does get connected, my entire screen freezes after some time, nothing works and the only option is to manually power off. During shutdown, I keep getting the following messages (copied from logs):

```
 8:23:57 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: Timeout for driver own
 8:23:57 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: Timeout for driver own
 8:23:57 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
 8:23:57 AM kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5:    [21] ACSViol                (First)
 8:23:57 AM kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5:    [21] ACSViol                (First)
 8:23:57 AM kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5:   device [8086:06b5] error status/mask=00200000/00010000
 8:23:57 AM kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Receiver ID)
 8:23:57 AM kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: DPC: unmasked uncorrectable error detected
 8:23:57 AM kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: DPC: containment event, status:0x1f01 source:0x0000
 8:23:57 AM kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: AER: device recovery failed
 8:23:57 AM kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: AER: subordinate device reset failed
 8:23:57 AM kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5: DPC: Data Link Layer Link Active not set in 1000 msec
 8:23:56 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: driver own failed
 8:23:56 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: driver own failed
 8:23:55 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: Timeout for driver own
 8:23:55 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
 8:23:55 AM kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5:    [21] ACSViol                (First)
 8:23:54 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: driver own failed
 8:23:52 AM kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5:    [21] ACSViol                (First)
 8:23:51 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: driver own failed
 8:23:50 AM kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5:    [21] ACSViol                (First)
 8:23:50 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: Timeout for driver own
 8:23:50 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: Timeout for driver own
 8:23:49 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: driver own failed
 8:23:48 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
 8:23:48 AM kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.5:    [21] ACSViol                (First)
 8:23:48 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: Timeout for driver own
```

I tried using a distro with a newer kernel (6.2) but the same issue is persisting.
The driver isn't blacklisted. I have checked `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

Output of `sudo lshw -class network`:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 15
       serial: 50:eb:f6:30:ce:b9
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-38-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c4204000-c4204fff memory:c4200000-c4203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: d
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: wlx3460f9f473f7
       serial: 34:60:f9:f4:73:f7
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu driverversion=5.19.0-38-generic ip=192.168.252.235 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 10th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 05)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 06d3
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b6 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake LPC Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5404 (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

As one can see the mediatek card is not detected. I wish I could the output of these commands when my card was detected but unfortunately my card isn't being detected right now.

Some people have also suggested to hold the power button for 60s while booting that also isn't working. The problem started around October 2022. I have tried disabling fast startup and Secure Boot but my wifi card still isn't detected.

Comment: Since this is happening in both Windows and Ubuntu it appears you have defective or failing hardware.